# could not build objective-c module 'Twitterkit' [IOS-Twitter-Fabric ]

Tags: ios, swift

i am doing twitter fabric integration in iOS using swift,during this when i  passing through step 1 but building the app i got error as "could not build objective-c module 'Twitterkit', please give me solution for that problem.

Comment: Check out this answer:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/could-not-build-objective-c-module-twitterkit/49551/7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not build Objective-C module 'TwitterKit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841804/could-not-build-objective-c-module-twitterkit)