# Could not build Objective-C module 'TwitterKit'

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm trying to install TwitterKit on my project via Fabric, but got stuck on this issue:

Could not build Objective-C module 'TwitterKit'

I'm using Swift and TwitterKit (2.2.0)

I've attempted to clean derived data, clean build folder already, doesn't work.

Attempted this solution as well, but didn't work for me:
https://twittercommunity.com/t/could-not-build-objective-c-module-twitterkit/49551
[image]

Here is the error:

[image]

Does anybody have a solution for this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had same problem yesterday. Add bridging header and inside import fabric and twitter. Worked like a charm

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: What you had written in bridging header ? I am having same issue so?

Comment: #import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
Sorry for delay in answer, hope this will help

Comment: @Atan: I am having the same problem. Could you please expand on this answer? I am not sure which files to place the #import statements.

Answer (score 3):

There's a slight chance that the deployment target value of the project's target is lower than that the TwitterKit supports.

In my case this was the problem. If the above solution does not work, you may check if the __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED value in TWTRKit.h is compatible with the target's settings.

Comment: This worked for me. It looks like TwitterKit doesn't support deployment targets below 9.0.