# cs193p "Could not build objective-C module Twitter"

Tags: xcode, twitter, swift3, cs193p

When I drag the `Twitter.xcodeproj` into the workspace alongside `Smashtag.xcodeproj`, the `Twitter.framework`is red-flagged.

When I add

```
import Twitter
```

the compiler throws an error saying

```
Could not build objective-C module "Twitter"
```

I've seen the suggestions on the previous thread, but

1. when I try to convert the Twitter.framework to Swift3 when it's open by itself, it says that it already is in Swift3,

or

2. if I go to ***Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax*** while in the workspace, the only option I get is the Smashtag.app

I'm certain that both `Twitter.framework` and `Smashtag.app` are in Swift3, yet the compiler throws an error saying that it can't build.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: which version of Twitter Kit are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to bypass the errors --> All I had to do was create a plank "twitter.h" file in the Twitter workspace, and all of the "could not build objective-c module" errors and compiled without issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not build Objective-C module 'TwitterKit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841804/could-not-build-objective-c-module-twitterkit)